# FileReference.save not working in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe

I'm trying to save a file in a flex web app using filereference's save function, but a dialog box never pops up. I know the docs say it can only be called in reaction to user input, so I put the call to save in the button's click function like so

```
<mx:Button label="Save" click="clickCallback(event)"/>
```

and the callback looks like

```
private function clickCallback(event:MouseEvent):void {
            Alert.show("Do save");
            mFile.save(mData); 
        }
```

The alert shows up, but no dialog box ever shows up.

Comment: Is **mFile** initialized at the moment you call this method?

Comment: I had thought it was, but after going back to check, no it wasn't. That got it working.